# Get last vision of one column after partitionBy function

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

```
+---------------+---------+-----------------+-------+-------------------+-----------+--------------------+--------------------+---------------+-------+-------------------+-------------------+
|ID_NOTIFICATION|ID_ENTITE|ID_ENTITE_GARANTE|CD_ETAT|DT_ETAT            |CD_ANOMALIE|CD_TYPE_DESTINATAIRE|CD_TYPE_EVENEMENT   |CD_SYS_APPELANT|TYP_MVT|DT_DEBUT           |DT_FIN             |
+---------------+---------+-----------------+-------+-------------------+-----------+--------------------+--------------------+---------------+-------+-------------------+-------------------+
|3110305        |GNE      |GNE              |AT     |2019-06-12 00:03:14|null       |null                |REL_CP_ULTIME_PAPIER|SIGMA          |C      |2019-06-12 00:03:22|2019-06-12 00:03:32|
|3110305        |GNE      |GNE              |AN     |2019-06-12 00:03:28|017        |IDGRC               |REL_CP_ULTIME_PAPIER|SIGMA          |M      |2019-06-12 00:03:22|2019-06-12 15:08:43|
|3110305        |GNE      |GNE              |AN     |2019-06-12 00:03:28|017        |IDGRC               |REL_CP_ULTIME_PAPIER|SIGMA          |M      |2019-06-12 00:03:22|2019-06-12 15:10:06|
|3110305        |GNE      |GNE              |AN     |2019-06-12 15:10:02|017        |IDGRC               |REL_CP_ULTIME_PAPIER|SIGMA          |M      |2019-06-12 00:03:22|2019-06-12 15:10:51|
|3110305        |GNE      |GNE              |AN     |2019-06-12 15:10:02|017        |IDGRC               |REL_CP_ULTIME_PAPIER|SIGMA          |M      |2019-06-12 00:03:22|2019-06-12 15:11:35|
```

I used PartitionBy function to only get one row of each distinct `CD_ETAT` column:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val window = Window.partitionBy("CD_ETAT").orderBy("DT_ETAT")

df.withColumn("row_num", row_number().over(window))
  .filter($"row_num" === 1)
  .drop("row_num")
```

Output:

```
+---------------+---------+-----------------+-------+-------------------+-----------+--------------------+--------------------+---------------+-------+-------------------+-------------------+
|ID_NOTIFICATION|ID_ENTITE|ID_ENTITE_GARANTE|CD_ETAT|            DT_ETAT|CD_ANOMALIE|CD_TYPE_DESTINATAIRE|   CD_TYPE_EVENEMENT|CD_SYS_APPELANT|TYP_MVT|           DT_DEBUT|             DT_FIN|
+---------------+---------+-----------------+-------+-------------------+-----------+--------------------+--------------------+---------------+-------+-------------------+-------------------+
|        3110305|      GNE|              GNE|     AT|2019-06-12 00:03:14|       null|                null|REL_CP_ULTIME_PAPIER|          SIGMA|      C|2019-06-12 00:03:22|2019-06-12 00:03:32|
|        3110305|      GNE|              GNE|     AN|2019-06-12 00:03:28|        017|               IDGRC|REL_CP_ULTIME_PAPIER|          SIGMA|      M|2019-06-12 00:03:22|2019-06-12 15:08:43|
+---------------+---------+-----------------+-------+-------------------+-----------+--------------------+--------------------+---------------+-------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

My question is: Is there a way to modify the code so each row that corresponds to each CD_ETAT gets the DT_FIN that corresponds to its last vision and not first.

Desired Output:

```
+---------------+---------+-----------------+-------+-------------------+-----------+--------------------+--------------------+---------------+-------+-------------------+-------------------+
|ID_NOTIFICATION|ID_ENTITE|ID_ENTITE_GARANTE|CD_ETAT|            DT_ETAT|CD_ANOMALIE|CD_TYPE_DESTINATAIRE|   CD_TYPE_EVENEMENT|CD_SYS_APPELANT|TYP_MVT|           DT_DEBUT|             DT_FIN|
+---------------+---------+-----------------+-------+-------------------+-----------+--------------------+--------------------+---------------+-------+-------------------+-------------------+
|        3110305|      GNE|              GNE|     AT|2019-06-12 00:03:14|       null|                null|REL_CP_ULTIME_PAPIER|          SIGMA|      C|2019-06-12 00:03:22|2019-06-12 00:03:32|
|        3110305|      GNE|              GNE|     AN|2019-06-12 00:03:28|        017|               IDGRC|REL_CP_ULTIME_PAPIER|          SIGMA|      M|2019-06-12 00:03:22|2019-06-12 15:11:35|
+---------------+---------+-----------------+-------+-------------------+-----------+--------------------+--------------------+---------------+-------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fot this you need two `Window` function as below

```
val window = Window.partitionBy("CD_ETAT").orderBy("DT_ETAT")
val window1 = Window.partitionBy("CD_ETAT").orderBy($"DT_FIN".desc)

//groupBy CD_ETAT and get the last DT_FIN and
df.withColumn("DT_FIN", first($"DT_FIN").over(window1))
   //groupBy CD_ETAT and get first DT_ETAT 
  .withColumn("row_num", row_number().over(window))
  .filter($"row_num" === 1 )
  .drop("row_num")
  .show()
```

Output:

```
+---------------+---------+-----------------+-------+-------------------+-----------+--------------------+--------------------+---------------+-------+-------------------+-------------------+
|ID_NOTIFICATION|ID_ENTITE|ID_ENTITE_GARANTE|CD_ETAT|            DT_ETAT|CD_ANOMALIE|CD_TYPE_DESTINATAIRE|   CD_TYPE_EVENEMENT|CD_SYS_APPELANT|TYP_MVT|           DT_DEBUT|             DT_FIN|
+---------------+---------+-----------------+-------+-------------------+-----------+--------------------+--------------------+---------------+-------+-------------------+-------------------+
|        3110305|      GNE|              GNE|     AT|2019-06-12 00:03:14|       null|                null|REL_CP_ULTIME_PAPIER|          SIGMA|      C|2019-06-12 00:03:22|2019-06-12 00:03:32|
|        3110305|      GNE|              GNE|     AN|2019-06-12 00:03:28|        017|               IDGRC|REL_CP_ULTIME_PAPIER|          SIGMA|      M|2019-06-12 00:03:22|2019-06-12 15:11:35|
+---------------+---------+-----------------+-------+-------------------+-----------+--------------------+--------------------+---------------+-------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want first row of all fields but one, you can use the [`last`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$) function combined with your window :

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val window = Window.partitionBy("CD_ETAT").orderBy("DT_ETAT")

df.withColumn("row_num", row_number() over window)
  .withColumn("DT_FIN", last($"DT_FIN") over window) //Extract last DT_FIN value of window
  .filter($"row_num" === 1)
  .drop("row_num")
```

This way, no need for a new window.

Comment: That returns the whole last row. I only need the value of DT_FIN column from last row and the rest of columns should stay like the second one

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I've edited my answer. Could you please check if it fits your needs ?